# What is best practice for sharing config files across multiple functions in an AWS API Gateway?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am deploying an API Gateway to AWS that has multiple endpoints, grouped into multiple groups.  In the interests of speed, readability and reusability, I've deployed this as a set of different lambda functions, one per group.  In the interests of portability I've defined it all in one cloudformation template.

So file structure looks somewhat like this:

```
package_name
|
| - group1/
|    |- handler1.py
|        | def function11(event, context):
|               ...
|        | def function12(event, context):
|               ...
| - group2/
|    |- handler2.py
|        | def function21(event, context):
|               ...
|        | def function22(event, context):
|               ...
| - config.py
|      S3_BUCKET_NAME = "my_bucket"
| - template.yaml
       Resources:
         Group1Function:
           Properties:
             CodeUri: group1/
             Handler: handler1.function11
               ...etc...
```

... corresponding to endpoints

```
<url>/group1/function11 
<url>/group1/function12
<url>/group2/function21 
<url>/group2/function22
```

The intent is that when endpoint function11 is requested, lambda only loads handler1.py, when function22 is requested it only loads handler2.py, and so on.

Question: what is the best approach for sharing common config options across multiple functions?  Normally I would put them in /config then import that into each function:

```
from package_name.config import S3_BUCKET_NAME
```

...but in this case I think cloudformation only packages the code in group1/ and group2/ for deployment, which doesn't include config.

What's the best approach to scale up to a large deployment with a lot of endpoints and quite a lot of config options?